# Cannot find name 'browser' error in typescript when trying to add onMessageExternal method for Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firefox, firefox-addon

Cannot find name 'browser' error in typescript when trying to add onMessageExternal method for Firefox Extension

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the "browser" a variable or do you mean document.addEventlLstener?

Comment: Trying to replicate this: they don't have browser declared, nor it is document.addEventListener. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

Answer (score 2):

Had the same question myself. Found [this response](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/cannot-find-name-browser-typescript-error/108670) recommending you install the [@types/firefox-webext-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/firefox-webext-browser) package. Seemed to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem before but

adding
/`*global browser*/`
at top of the file will resolve  your problem
also if you get the same error for `runtime` you can do the same for that